# Return entire record of max value

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT * FROM car

test-# ;

  id  |     make      |          model          |  price
------+---------------+-------------------------+----------
    1 | GMC           | Sonoma Club             | 59705.11
    2 | Nissan        | Pathfinder              | 97737.00
    3 | GMC           | Savana 3500             | 19930.80
    4 | Honda         | Passport                | 38793.10
    5 | Pontiac       | GTO                     | 34637.61
```

This is my car database
I want to return the max price of the car from the `price` column. When I use the query `SELECT MAX(price) FROM car;` it only returns the max value of the price as below

```
test=# SELECT MAX(price) FROM car;
   max
----------
 99897.25
(1 row)
```

I want to return the car name and model name of the car as well along with the price.

Comment: Please post your data as text and also include your specific desired results...  so for make GMC, what values do you expect to come back?

Comment: posting data as text is not giving proper results, please check, How can I show small database picture here

Comment: The dataset is small enough, can you please post exactly the output you expect to see?  Just like you did with the input data, but include your specific desired results.  Maybe it's just me, but I'm still unclear of what you seek.

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5b231b3c05e4e84200301ab5347bb59c)

You can order your table by `price DESC` to the record with the highest `price` the first records. Then you can `LIMIT` your output to this one record.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM car
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @AkshayNarwadkar Did this help? Please don't forget to UPVOTE any helpful answer. This honors the time and effort the repliers invested into your problem. If one answer solves your problem, please ACCEPT it additionally to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible that 2 or more cars could have the same price for max. Then do you want to randomly choose 1 of them, or list them all. If the latter then:

```
select *
  from car
 where price = (select max(price)
                  from car
               ) 
order by id;
```